# Common APIs to launch EC2 and Openstack instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, openstack-nova

At work we use Amazon linux Ec2 instances for production purposes. Also, for our internal dev setup we use openstack Cent OS instances.

I want to make a common CLI or expose REST APIs to start and stop instances on both these cloudstacks. (I already have machine images). I understand I can use any of the common SDKs (I plan to use GO) and build this.

Recently, I came across [this](https://github.com/openstack/ec2-api). I am just wondering if such a thing is already available. Or does the above repo mean something else? There have been also some other articles which mention EC2 support for openstack. I am not sure if it means the same as I what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There already is some compatibility with ec2 command line clients, for Nova, what you have linked to expands on that to include some network functions (VPC etc.), and openstack heat is compatible with some aws cloudformation templates.

have you looked at euca2ools? - this client was developed by Eucalyptus cloud and is compatible with AWS and nova EC2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking at it now. However, I can't get it to work. I have created a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931910/managing-ec2-instances-with-euca2ools-cli) for the same.

Comment: Also, when you say there is some compatibility with nova, does it mean I can use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) for both Openstack and AWS to just start and stop instances?

Comment: euca2ools client can be used on both AWS EC2 and Openstack Nova EC2 compatible endpoints. For starting and stopping instances you can use this one client.- Go to you horizon dashboard and under access and security >> API Access,  download the EC2 credentails, installed the euca2ools package from the Ubuntu multiverse and them source the EC2 credentails file to export you credentials and endpoints, then try, euca-describe-images, now load your AWS credentials and run the same command.

Comment: I installed devstack and did like u suggested, when I run `euca-describe-images` , I get the following error `euca-describe-images: error (403): 403 Forbidden`

Comment: I posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958235/error-403-403-forbidden-on-using-euca2ools-against-openstack) with details.