# error (403): 403 Forbidden on using euca2ools against openstack

Tags: amazon-ec2, openstack-nova, eucalyptus

I want to use [ecua2ools](https://github.com/eucalyptus/euca2ools) against openstack nova service and AWS EC2. I have managed to get it working for AWS. I am trying to do the same for openstack.

I installed devstack from [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/). But, I couldn't see `EC2 API` on  horizon. So, I installed back using [this](https://github.com/openstack/ec2-api). Now, I could see the `EC2 API` option. I downloaded the `EC2 credentials`.

Then, I created `/etc/euca2ools/euca2ools.ini` file and I had the following contents inside.

```
[user mv2-dev]
key-id = df20573bf4554a369f61641b21e6c659
secret-key = 5b83c91991d141c9ac009010fc71c384

[region local]
ec2-url = http://192.168.100.103:8788/
user = mv2-dev

[global]
default-region = local
```

When I run this command `euca-describe-images`, I get the following error.

```
euca-describe-images: error (403): 403 Forbidden

Timestamp failed validation.
```

I am not sure where do I check more logs for it.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a time difference between your server and the workstation. Use NTP to keep the clocks synchronised.